# How to add readable name and description to templates?

Tags: block-editor, page-template

I created  `single-post-type-name.html` in `templates` but they show up like this in the dashboard:

[image]

Is there a way to have it like "Single Post Type Name" and also add a description like the Single template that says "The default template for displaying...."?

That `single.html` does not have any description, so I guess that description is added by default?

https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentytwentythree/1.0/templates/single.html?rev=178734

Comment: The filename `single` is reserved by WordPress to mean a template for any single post or page. Take a look [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png) at the list of reserved name and their hierarchy. You'd be able to get that name to show up by adding the correct template comments as shown [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/#example). Let me know if that's what you're looking for and I can post a proper answer to mark as resolved.

Comment: FYI You'll need a .php file for that to work, rename your file to `single-post-type-name.php`.

Comment: @YourManDan you don't need to rename it, it actually works having it as html. This is a block theme based on TwentyTwentyThree theme I attached.

Comment: Right, it will show up fine in that list, but in order to get the "Single Post Type Name", you'll need to have the file as PHP, and then use the comment structure in the second link I sent you.

Comment: That description is generated somewhere in WP; not yet possible to add your custom description - https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/44097

Comment: Apologies also, @Will made me realize I posted the wrong link for naming your template file. [This](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-page-templates-for-specific-post-types) is the correct link.

Comment: @Will thanks, looks like you can rename it but cant add description yet

Comment: @YourManDan Just so you know, all your comments are describing how custom page templates work in classic themes. The question is regarding block theme templates which uses a relatively new system that works completely different to classic themes: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/block-themes/

Answer (score 1):

To add a readable title to a template, we can add the following to `theme.json`

```
"customTemplates": [
        {
            "name": "single-post-type-name",
            "title": "Single Post Type Name"
        },
 ...
```

But as Will mentioned in the comments, it is not possible to add descriptions yet. There is an issue to track it here: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/44097